# How to determine number of tests required for a method?

Tags: java, testing

By looking at a method, is there a rule of thumb or a way in which we can determine the statement coverage (or the number of tests) that would be required for a method?

```
int v(int c, int d) {
  if (c > d) {
    return c;
   }

   int x=0;
   for (int i=c;i<=d;++i) {
          if (i%2==0) {
             x+=c;
           }
             x+=c;
           }
           return x;
}
```

Comment: There is not a general rule of thumb for determining the number of test cases you should have for a method, but you should ensure that all cases and especially edge cases (inputs that might lead to weird behavior). This method is pretty simple and there don't seem to be a lot edge cases. One edge case would be with c = multiples of two, because of your i % 2 check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If statement coverage is your sole target, you may want to use for example the "Coverage As" package explorer contextmenu item in Eclipse. It highlights which statements in code are covered in unit tests and which aren't.

It doesn't state the required amount of tests up front but is useful to display current coverage.